# how to sort elements and group them based on unique element or ID

Tags: xslt

how do i sort the elements based on "CorporationID" and group them..

I have an xml payload something like the below one ...

```
 <corporationActions>
  <corporationAction>
    <ActionID>5530974</ActionID>
    <CorporationID>1044294</CorporationID>
    <ActionDate>2009-05-03</ActionDate>
    <ActionType>Articles of Organization2</ActionType>
    <ActionNotes></ActionNotes>
    <DocumentNumber>20110258775-68</DocumentNumber>
    <NumberofPages>4</NumberofPages>
  </corporationAction>
  <corporationAction>
    <ActionID>5530975</ActionID>
    <CorporationID>1044294</CorporationID>
    <ActionDate>2009-05-03</ActionDate>
    <ActionType>Miscellaneous</ActionType>
    <ActionNotes></ActionNotes>
    <DocumentNumber>20110258777-80</DocumentNumber>
    <NumberofPages>2</NumberofPages>
  </corporationAction>
</corporationActions>
```

i need to first sort the elements based on **CorporationID** and then group them if the **CorporationID** s are repeating.. like the below paylaod

```
<corporationActions>
    <corporationAction>
        <CorporationID>1044294</CorporationID>
        <corporationActionDetails>
            <ActionID>5530974</ActionID>
            <ActionDate>2009-05-03</ActionDate>
            <ActionType>Articles of Organization2</ActionType>
        </corporationActionDetails>
        <corporationActionDetails>
            <ActionID>5530975</ActionID>
            <ActionDate>2009-05-03</ActionDate>
            <ActionType>Miscellaneous</ActionType>
        </corporationActionDetails>
    </corporationAction>
</corporationActions>
```

Thanks & Regards,
anvv sharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is an XSLT 1.0 grouping (Muenchian method) solution, that is mostly in push-style using templates and no `<xsl:for-each>`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kcorpActByID" match="corporationAction"
  use="CorporationID"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
         <xsl:sort select="CorporationID" data-type="number"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "corporationAction|CorporationID
 |ActionNotes|DocumentNumber|NumberofPages"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "corporationAction
    [generate-id()
    =
     generate-id(key('kcorpActByID', CorporationID)[1])
     ]">
  <corporationAction>
   <xsl:copy-of select="CorporationID"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
    select="key('kcorpActByID',CorporationID)" />
  </corporationAction>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="corporationAction" mode="copy">
  <corporationActionDetails>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </corporationActionDetails>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<corporationActions>
  <corporationAction>
    <ActionID>5530974</ActionID>
    <CorporationID>1044294</CorporationID>
    <ActionDate>2009-05-03</ActionDate>
    <ActionType>Articles of Organization2</ActionType>
    <ActionNotes></ActionNotes>
    <DocumentNumber>20110258775-68</DocumentNumber>
    <NumberofPages>4</NumberofPages>
  </corporationAction>
  <corporationAction>
    <ActionID>5530975</ActionID>
    <CorporationID>1044294</CorporationID>
    <ActionDate>2009-05-03</ActionDate>
    <ActionType>Miscellaneous</ActionType>
    <ActionNotes></ActionNotes>
    <DocumentNumber>20110258777-80</DocumentNumber>
    <NumberofPages>2</NumberofPages>
  </corporationAction>
</corporationActions>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<corporationActions>
   <corporationAction>
      <CorporationID>1044294</CorporationID>
      <corporationActionDetails>
         <ActionID>5530974</ActionID>
         <ActionDate>2009-05-03</ActionDate>
         <ActionType>Articles of Organization2</ActionType>
      </corporationActionDetails>
      <corporationActionDetails>
         <ActionID>5530975</ActionID>
         <ActionDate>2009-05-03</ActionDate>
         <ActionType>Miscellaneous</ActionType>
      </corporationActionDetails>
   </corporationAction>
</corporationActions>
```

**Do note**: The added flexibility due to the use and overriding of the identity template. In contrast of `<xsl:copy-of select="ActionID|ActionDate|ActionType"/>` we use: `<xsl:apply-templates/>` and this assures that any of the children of the current node can be processed in any way we want (and further specify in separate templates).

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="corporationAction"
       group-by="CorporationID">
   <xsl:sort select="number(CorporationID)"/>

   <corporationAction>
    <xsl:sequence select="CorporationID"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
     select="current-group()" />
   </corporationAction>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="corporationAction" mode="copy">
  <corporationActionDetails>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </corporationActionDetails>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=
 "corporationAction|CorporationID
 |ActionNotes|DocumentNumber|NumberofPages"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note**: the simplified grouping using `<xsl:for-each-group>` and the `current-group()` function.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses Muenchian method:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
 <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="bycorporationid" match="corporationActions/corporationAction" use="CorporationID"/>

 <xsl:template match="corporationActions">
  <corporationActions>
   <xsl:for-each select="corporationAction[count(. | key('bycorporationid', CorporationID)[1]) = 1]">

    <xsl:sort select="CorporationID" />

     <corporationAction>
      <CorporationID><xsl:value-of select="CorporationID"/></CorporationID>

       <xsl:for-each select="key('bycorporationid',CorporationID)">
        <corporationActionDetails>
          <xsl:copy-of select="ActionID"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="ActionDate"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="ActionType"/>
        </corporationActionDetails>
      </xsl:for-each>

     </corporationAction>

   </xsl:for-each>
  </corporationActions>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: the above xslt is not working if i have namespaces in the corresponding xml e.g.,

Comment: Obviously not, this was not mentioned in your question and not deducible from your input sample. If you are not able to fix it by yourself, please expand the question with the new requirement. we'll see how to fix it.

Comment: <FinalId><FDb xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/FinalId" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/FinalId"><ns0:USERUBSCRIBERS><ns0:USER_ID>237</ns0:USER_ID><ns0:BusinessEntity><ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID>NV0511201114</ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID><ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID>207</ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID></ns0:BusinessEntity></ns0:USERUBSCRIBERS><ns0:USERUBSCRIBERS><ns0:USER_ID>237</ns0:USER_ID><ns0:BusinessEntity><ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID>NV0511201119</ns0:NEVADA_BUSINESS_ID><ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID>212</ns0:BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID></ns0:BusinessEntity></ns0:USERUBSCRIBERS></FDb></FinalId>

Comment: Please do not use comment. Edit your question (better) or add a new answer if you can't do that.